# Update folder structure in VS Tools for cordova to support CLI interoperability (VS2015RC)

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I see that VS2015RC support the more cordova suggested folder structure, and CLI interoperability. Are there any docs that describe how to modify existing apps to use this new feature? I've build an app based on this the VS2013 [ionic starter template](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Ionic-SideMenu-Starter-8e905eb5) and would like to start using the ionic cli.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the docs for this are available yet, but this post (under Method 2) walks through getting the CLI project into a VS2015RC TACO project...

[Using Ionic with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://www.spritehand.com/2015/04/using-ionic-with-visual-studio-tools.html)

In general the steps are...

- create a Cordova project using CLI
- create a 2nd (empty) project using VS2015 RC Cordova (blank app) template
- from the VS project, copy the \merges, .jsproj, and taco.json to the CLI project folder
- Open the .jsproj and cross your fingers :)

Answer (score 2):

This [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-known-issues-vs) describes how you manually convert your existing apps to VS 2105 RC project structure. Let me know if you have problems accessing the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method I believe, which I have used -

1. Create a new Blank App using VS 2013/2015
2. Copy all the contents from your www folder from your existing project and paste it to the www folder of this blank app.
3. Build and enjoy!